# How to access an item in a list within a listed dictionary.

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I currently have a lot of customer data where each row of data is an individual interaction by a customer, but where some customers have had multiple interactions, thus many customers have multiple rows. Some variables in each of multiple-interaction customer rows are the same while others variables are different (ie. age may be the same, but different stores).

I have attempted to create a dictionary where customer id is the key and the row data is attached to the id. This means that attached to each key is a list of lists. I am thus trying to access an item (single variable) from a first interaction based on each unique customer from a slew of different interactions.

```
import sys
import re
import csv
from collections import defaultdict


def extract_data(filename):
  customer_list = {}
  count = 0
  counter = 1
  file = open(filename, 'r')
  reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
  for row in reader:
    if row[2] not in customer_list:
      customer_list[row[2]] = [row]
      count += 1
    else:
      customer_list[row[2]].append(row)

  print 'total number of customers: ', len(customer_list.keys())

  zipcodes = []
  numzips = 0
  for customer in customer_list:
    for item in customer.value():
      if item[1[7]] not in zipcodes:
        zipcodes.append(item[1[7]])
        numzips += 1
  print zipcodes
  print numzips
```

Note i'm pretty sure i can't use item[1[7]] to reference the first list and then the 7th item in the list, but i also do not want to iterate over each inner dictionary list for each item. I have gotten a range of different errors and really do not know how to proceed.

Any help / advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share sample data, it makes easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dictionary looks something like this :

customer_dict=

{
"cust_id_1" : [[item1],[item2,item3],[item4,item5]],

"cust_id_2" : [[item7],[item8],[item9,item10,item11]]
}

In order to access item4 , you can use customer_dict["cust_id1"][2][0]

Hope I got the intended dictionary right .